# Just curious how Android garbage collection works for startActivityForResult()

Tags: android

I have three activities: A, B, and C.

The Activity A will start Activity B with a long value passed with intent, and Activity B will save this long value in its instance variable.

Then, Activity B will startActivityForResult() the Activity C at some point.

But if I am understanding correctly, when Activity C is running, Activity B can be garbage corrected and therefore the instance variable of Activity B will be lost.

I wonder if the long value in Activity B will be garbage corrected or not.

For simplicity, Activity A ==[Intent with long value]==>  Activity B(will save long value in its instance) ==[startActivityForResult()]==>  Activity C

I'm assuming that I have to save the long value in savedInstanceState if that's the case.

But I also heard that the Intent created from Activity A somewhat remain, so the long value will be re-initialized when onCreate() is called.

Any idea please?

Comment: Activity instance is destroyed along with its fields. You can retain data via `onSaveInstanceState` and access it later in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. When the activity is recreated its original intent is redelivered so you can re-init from there, as has been said.

Comment: but isn't the Intent that has started the Activity will survive isn't it? Are the values saved in the Intent going to be persistent?

Comment: In `onCreate` you can `getIntent` that started the actvity. Values in that intent don't change. (And if you made some changes to the intent they wouldn't persist.)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. In your developer settings on your phone (sxroll all the way to the bottom) you can disable keep activities in memory. A great way to test your case.
Second. The intent arguments are kept. So when you go back from C to B your intent data is still there.